# Trying to cherry-pick from a feature branch: No "cherries"?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

(It's the first time I'm trying to use git's cherry picking, so maybe I misunderstood what it is or what it can do)

While working on some new feature in a feature branch (for simplicity let's call it just `next`), I discovered some bugs in the current `master` that I fixed "on the fly" (which may not have been the best idea). Now that I think the feature branch is complete, I'd like to cherry pick some or all of the bugs fixed in `next` to `master` to make a bug-fix release before a feature release.

So I checked out `master` and tried (after reading the git-cherry manual page):

```
git cherry
git cherry next
git cherry -v next
git cherry -v next master
```

However none of the commands did output anything, even though there is a huge difference between `next` and `master`.

So what is the problem? Did I do something wrong, or did I misunderstand about cherry picking? The manual refers to some "origin" branch, while my branch is local.

If the cherry picking is the wrong tool, what would be the correct procedure to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `cherry` is not `cherry-pick` though. It sounds like you want to `cherry-pick`, but you're using `cherry`...?

Comment: The manual page for `git-cherry` says: "Find commits yet to be applied to upstream". So my guess was that I can select a commit from this list for actual cherry-pick. But that list is empty (no cherries to pick, so to say).

Comment: `cherry` finds commits on _current_ branch that are not applied to the _upstream_ branch. I.e. while on `master`, it finds commits on _`master`_ that are not yet in _`next`_. You want the vice versa: `git cherry master next` (or `git checkout next; git cherry master`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git cherry` and `git cherry-pick` are two different commands.
From source [git cherry](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry):
`git cherry [-v] [<upstream> [<head> [<limit>]]]` will show you a ID's of commits which are missing from `head` on `upstream`. In your case  `git cherry next master` didn't show anything cause there are no commits on `master`, which are not present on `next` branch. You can check the other way `git cherry master next` and you will see all `next` commits ID's, which are not present on `master`.

Once you will know id's of commits, which you want to [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) do this with `git cherry-pick commitID`

Comment: What confused me is: Manual says "`git-cherry` [*upstream* [*head*]]" with *head* defaulting to the workspace. So I guessed "git cherry next" would look for commits in `next` that are missing in the workspace (`master`). Basically I concluded from the manual that *upstream* is the more recent branch, while actually it's just reversed.